# black screen after power on & auto power on after force shutdown

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, hardware-failure

After pressing the power button of the laptop, most of the hardware is completely unresponsive.

- The fan works for a few seconds and stops. It works for a short time before stops again periodically after that. (Low workload?)
- The backlight of the keyboard doesn't work.
- The screen shows nothing.
- Lights on the USB mouse are not lit.
- After force shutdown by holding the power button, it sometimes restart automatically.

I have tried to blindly input F2+F9+enter+F10+enter to reset the bios and drain residual electricity by holding the power button.

It seems to me a hardware failure. Does the automatic restart imply a short circuit somewhere in the motherboard?

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot shorted or blown parts.  Take the machine to a local computer shop and have it diagnosed properly.

Comment: Problems with the fans at startup usually indicate the power supply.

Comment: Did you remove the battery and charger, and then press and hold the power button for 30 seconds?

Comment: @Toni Yes, and I also tried removing and installing RAM. Some sources say removing the CMOS battery will help, but I can't find one on the motherboard.

Comment: Some laptops don't have a CMOS battery. I think you need to send your machine to a repair shop.